How can I obtain an option (get_option) inside a block viewScript?
If I traditionally enqueue a script...
wp_enqueue_script('some-script', $dependencies_script_path, array( 'wp-i18n' ), false, $load_in_footer);

I can use wp_add_inline_script to send info from wp_option table to the front end javascript this way:
$beautiful_option = get_option('beautiful');
wp_add_inline_script('some-script', 'const BEAUTIFUL_OPTION=' .$beautiful_option, 'before');

And then, in the javascript file, I can, magically access the constant:
doMagicalThingsWith(BEAUTIFUL_OPTION);

How can I do this on the viewScript of a block?

So, if I want to add any custom styles or scripts in a block's CSS or JS file, I usually add them in the PHP file associated with the block (the render property in block.json).
Add the following code to the PHP file at the end -
$beautiful_option = get_option('beautiful');
wp_add_inline_script('some-script', 'const BEAUTIFUL_OPTION=' .$beautiful_option, 'before');

Just make sure to add any appropriate checks and validations for the code.
Seems a bit hacky but has worked so far for me.
